# How To Get Higest And Lowest Bar index

Tags: pine-script, mql4

Hello This is my script i convert that from MQL4 to Pinescript it's not Working i test llb and hhb return that was value of of index not that index how can i fix it ?

```
// This source code is subject to the terms of the Mozilla Public License 2.0 at https://mozilla.org/MPL/2.0/
// © hesamx98

//@version=4
study("My Script")

hhb = highest(high,bar_index)[24]
llb = lowest(low,bar_index)[24]

if bar_index == hhb
    label.set_text(hhb, "Buy")
    label.set_color(hhb, color.green)
    label.set_yloc(hhb, yloc.belowbar)
    label.set_style(hhb, label.style_labelup)
    
if bar_index == llb
    label.set_text(llb, "Sell")
    label.set_color(llb, color.red)
    label.set_yloc(llb, yloc.abovebar)
    label.set_style(llb, label.style_labeldown)
```

Answer (score 0):

You're passing in `bar_index` for the `length` parameter of the functions `highest` and `lowest` which doesn't make sense...and then are asking for the value of that from 24 bars ago.

I'm guessing you're intending to do something like this:

```
hhb = highest(high, 24)
```

Comment: Thanks I Want Translate this line from mql4 to pinescript in that line : hhb = iHighest(NULL,0,MODE_HIGH,24,i-12);